# pseudo-elements display: block vs display: inline

Tags: html, css

I am currently practicing CSS by following along with a Youtube tutorial by freecodecamp.org

My code is as follows:

```css
p::before{
  content: "hello ";
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  background: salmon;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p::after{
  display: block;
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Before and after pseudo elements</p>
```

Now when I specify display: block in the p:: after pseudo-selector I am getting the expected output as follows

[image]

but when I omit the display: block property, the green box just disappears as below:

[image]

Does someone have an appropriate explanation for why this happens? What I was expecting was that the box will still be shown inline after the 'hello before and after pseudo-elements' but it is disappearing altogether...

Thanks in Advance for the help.

Kind Regards,
Sohaib

Comment: Because the `content` is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then use `display: inline-block`

Elements with `display: inline` can't have explicit dimensions set on them - it will have no effect. And so, because the pseudo element has no non-empty content, it will appear with 0 dimensions and thus invisible.

Comment: Thanks for this! Clear and concise! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block;` to your CSS

```css
p::before{
  content: "hello ";
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  background: salmon;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p::after{
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Before and after pseudo elements</p>
```